# Master-Details SplitViewController Custom UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I have a Master-Details project setup and running in XCode with no problems at all and everything works fine. However, when I attempt to round the top right and left corners of the NavigationBar it has a very strange effect. It basically, offsets the 'touch' response of the 'back' left button on the details view.

The button still works, but it seems that the iPhone can only pick up the user's touch when they click just below the NavigationBar and not the button itself.

The code I have is:

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor *color = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-bar"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    self.tintColor = color;

    // Create mask to round corners
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    // Apply mask to navigation bar
    [self.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    // Apply logo to navigation bar
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo"]];
    self.topItem.titleView = imageView;
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what I mean, button only responses when I touch where the arrow is pointing:

[image: Touch Point]

--- UPDATE ---

After some testing I've worked out the problem is with the 'self.layer.mask = maskLayer' line. I have refactored the code and tested in another project that just uses xib files and not story boards, and dont have any problems, but its still not working in the current project.

```
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.width,
                                   navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height);
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

        // Apply mask to navigation bar
        //navigationController.navigationBar.layer.mask = maskLayer;
        [navigationController.navigationBar.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
        navigationController.navigationBar.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: I should point out, I have worked out its because of the 'mask'; because if I remove it I dont have any problems.

Comment: are u still doin the above update in the drawRect method? you can use directly navigationController.navigationBar.bounds instead of having a bounds local var

Comment: also if it works on the storyboard it should work too on the xib files. I prefer to work on the storyboard though over xib to visualize all the scenes

Comment: I am no longer using the drawRect method, but using the 'navigationController.navigationBar...' directly.The code works when used against xib files but not story boards, it's very strange. The touch point of the button seems to be offset by the height of a status bar when a mask is applied to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `self.bounds` instead of `self.frame`. You probably want to draw relatively to your own coordinates system and not relatively to your own parent view.

Comment: do u really need to edit your drawRect actually it's not that a good idea performance wise. Have you consider just changing the cornerRadius of your self.view? (self.view.layer.cornerRadius)

Comment: OK, I can around the corners of the view using cornerRadius, but how to I make sure I only round the top left and right?

Comment: You will need to apply a mask as you did. But what you did can be done within the initWithFrame method if you are working on a UIView